Replacing null values with arrays inside a record repeated field BigQuery
I have a BQ table with a column "labels" of type RECORD and mode REPEATED (labels.key and labels.value) and would like to replace the null values of labels.value with an array of strings taken from another query, something like:
SELECT CASE WHEN label.values IS NULL THEN ARRAY[STRUCT(SELECT distinct string_values FROM other_table)] ELSE label.values END

That's wrong possibly for a number of reasons, but the main error returned is that I "cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING" ....
I would like to do that keeping the schema and the structure as it is, so without unnesting. That will come later but I need to prepare the table first replacing those null values.
Is there a way to do that?
